# How to reset all variables in memory using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, cron-task

Maybe my question is not exactly correct, but basically, I need to know the easiest way to reset all of my variables within my node js application using the npm package node cron (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

However, I think this is only happening with my arrays.

The package works great... My function is running on the scheduled interval, but each time it runs it does not release the previous scheduled tasks variables from memory. Essentially it appears that I am getting each iteration added into the last.

What is the best practice for releasing everything from memory so it does not keep the old data on each time the task runs.

Example:
***(run the function every minute)***

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  myFunction();
});
```

As mentioned above the function **myFunction()** runs each time via the node-cron library. However, the variables inside this function appear to not get released from the memory on each run of the scheduled cron task.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess it's the way you are referencing variables in `myFunction` rather than something to do with node-cron. If you can provide some code of how you are using variables in the function it will be easier for people to help answer

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best practice for releasing everything from memory so it does not keep the old data on each time the task runs.

There is no such convention or feature in Javascript to release all variables.

If you declare variables properly within a function or block scope, then those variables will only survive as long as that scope is alive.  If you don't properly declare your variables with `const`, `let` or `var`, then they may become accidental global variables and they will live for the duration of the whole application.

Do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // declare variables to be local to your function
    let x = 2;

    // bunch of other code that uses x

}
```

Then, each time `myFunction()` is run, there will be a new version of `x` that has nothing to do with the prior version of `x` and Javascript garbage collection will clean up the older versions that are no longer in use.

If you want more specific help with your code, then show us the code that uses the variables you are having issues with.

---

If you do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // declare variables to be local to your function
    x = 2;

    // bunch of other code that uses x

}
```

Then, `x` becomes an accidental global variable and the same `x` variable will be used in all invocations of `myFunction()`.  This is an anti-pattern in Javascript and, in fact, Javascript now has `strict` mode that even makes this an error because of how evil it is.  Intentional global variables should be explicitly declared as global.  All other variables should be intentionally declared within the appropriate function or block scope with `const`, `let` or `var`.

Comment: @jremi - If this answered your question, then please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and thus finished this question.  This will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As jfriend00 said I must have been using a function that had variables that accidentaly went global . I ended up doing some refactoring re-write and was able to resolve, now the service is working great. thank you